# Achieving the equivalence of ndb.StructuredProperty in new Cloud Datastore Mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In the old `ndb` Datastore, it is possible to create a `StructuredProperty`. This was thanks to the `ndb.Model` provided.

However, in the new Cloud Datastore, the ndb isn't available. So how could we implement a similar functionality as the ndb.StructuredProperty in the new Cloud Datastore?

I have a JobApplication model that has one or many Education and Experience objects:

```
class Education:
    def __init__(self, institution):
        institution = self.institution

class Experience:
    def __init__(self, workplace):
        workplace = self.workplace

class JobApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.educations = None
        self.experiences = None

    def add_education(self, education):
        self.educations.append(education)

    def add_experience(self, experience):
        self.experiences.append(experience)        


edu_1 = Education('aol')
edu_2 = Education('myspace')

jobapp = JobApplication()
jobapp.add_education(edu_1)
jobapp.add_education(edu_2)
```

While this kinda works for `reading` the entity, it becomes complex while trying to `update` the entity. For example, how would I be able to update `edu_2` within the `JobApplication` object?

Using the old ndb approach is very simple:

```
class Education(ndb.Model):
    institution = ndb.StringProperty()

class JobApplication(ndb.Model)
    education = ndb.StructuredProperty(Education, repeated=True)
```

How can I achieve this result using the new Cloud Datastore?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by new Cloud Datastore? [Per documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#structured) you can use Structured Properties. Could you share the error you are getting? This is the [Google Cloud App Engine Official Documentatio](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#Updating_entities) to update entities.

Comment: I think I just realized that The Cloud Datastore is not new, but the NDB for the Datastore library is new. Is it correct that the new NDB is now here: https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/index.html

Comment: Yes, it's there. Let me know if you were able to solve your issue.

Comment: Yes this issue is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can use [google-cloud-ndb](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/index.html) in environments other than first generation App Engine standard runtimes.  Thus you can continue to use StructuredProperty.